# take a photo with my own button without UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to take a photo with my own button in my app without using the `UIImagePickerController`. So, I want to have a view on my view controller which displays the live camera view and a button with an action where I can take directly a photo without using the `UIImagePickerController`. Then I want to display this photo in my view on my view controller.

The reason is that I don't want to have a second screen for taking the photo. The handling should be much easy. Or is there another solution to take a photo over my own handles?

I use Swift to do this.

At the moment I use the `UIImagePickerController` in my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2:UIViewController,UIAlertViewDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var btnClickMe: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var picker:UIImagePickerController?=UIImagePickerController()
    var popover:UIPopoverController?=nil

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        picker!.delegate=self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func btnImagePickerClicked(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        self.openCamera()
    }

    func openCamera()
    {
        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera))
        {
            picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            self.presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
        openGallary()
        }
    }

    func openGallary()
    {
        picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
        {
            self.presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            popover=UIPopoverController(contentViewController: picker!)
            popover!.presentPopoverFromRect(btnClickMe.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)
    {
        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        imageView.image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController!)
    {
        println("picker cancel.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to dig into avfoundation classes.and make your own controller.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2 have a look at this too